# MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast remote X11 windows

Tags: command-line, windows, xserver

I am connecting to my Ubuntu machine through SSH terminal from my windows machine and trying to open a graphical window using Xserve in windows. It loads the graphical interface but stops as this error appears on the terminal. libLLVM-7-rhel.so is in the folder.

libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: libLLVM-7-rhel.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /opt/Sc/lib:, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast